# Windows 10 boot ignores grub

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I followed the mainstream instructions for installing Ubuntu 16.10 alongside windows 10. After installing Ubuntu I restarted my computer to get the GRUB menu to choose which OS to boot. Everything is fine. Booted Ubuntu 16.10 and then I wanted to test Windows as well, so I shut the pc down and turned on again to find the same menu but this time I chose Windows. When I turned it on again, it just ignored grub and went straight to booting Windows.

EDIT: Windows 10 fast start and hibernation are disabled, Secure Boot is disabled; my notebook is a Sony Vaio SVE151J11X

EDIT2: through admin prompt on windows i just ran:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
```

now everything is fine. Thanks

Comment: Check the answer here: [Windows 10 upgrade kills grub and boot-repair doesn't help](//askubuntu.com/a/655279)

Answer (score 0):

You could try try `update-grub`, or booting off the live USB or Livecd and running `install-grub /dev/sda` with the hard drive mounted. This will reinstall GRUB and should check for other operating systems again.

Otherwise, install and use Boot-repair from a live session.

> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install boot-repair && boot-repair

check this: [Grub2](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2)

Or add this to sudo update-grub2

Another option add in **/etc/grub.d/40_custom** this:

`menuentry "Windows" {`

`set root=(hd0,2)`

`chainloader +1`

`}`

You might need to twiddle the numbers to get the right partition.

To try the last thing **you have to know your Windows 10 parition**.

so open bash..

> sudo update-grub2
>
> vi grub.cfg

** change the lines I have marked with ** # <--- change this** in your grub.cfg.

and then..

`sudo grub-install /dev/sda`

Comment: i did the repair-boot, didn't work. but i edited the question with the solution, thank you!